# How to set <iron-scroll-threshold> scroll-target to "document" for Polymer Starter Kit

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

I intend to implement an infinite scroller using  with PSK v3 by setting the `scroll-target` to `"document"`, but it just doesn't work for PSK. Below is the code snippet:

```html
<iron-scroll-threshold id="threshold"
    scroll-target="document"
    on-lower-threshold="queryMoreData">
  <iron-list items="[[items]]" grid>
    <template>
      <div>
        <div class="content">
          item: [[item.n]]
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </iron-list>
</iron-scroll-threshold>
```

I have tested `scroll-target="document"` with plain HTML, and it's working nicely. I want to know how should it be set for PSK to trigger an event when user scroll to the end of a particular page/view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you need to set the `scroll-target` of `<iron-scroll-threshold>` to the `scroll-target` of `<app-header>` with the following code in `ready()`:-

```js
ready() {
  { // Set scroll target for <iron-scroll-threshold>
    let myApp = document.querySelector('my-app');
    let appHeader = myApp.shadowRoot.querySelector('app-header');

    this.$.threshold.scrollTarget = appHeader.scrollTarget;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, your scroll position is at enough lower place at start than `queryMoreData` functions fire ones. In this function, you will need to clear the threshold by calling the `clearTriggers` method into `queryMoreData` function :

```
queryMoreData() {
    //check if you have more data to load than

    ironScrollTheshold.clearTriggers();
}
```

After which it will begin listening again for the scroll position to reach the threshold again assuming the content in the scrollable region has grown.

Comment: In my previous example, I have actually called `this.$.threshold.clearTriggers()` to clear the trigger in `queryMoreData()` function. it seems the problem is with wrong scroll target as there are a other scrollable element in the structure of PSK, such as app-drawer-layout/app-header-layout (which I am not very sure)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the **scroll-target** attribute of the `iron-scroll-threshold` element to '**document**'.

Also note the **scroll-target** attribute of the `iron-list` is set to the id of the `iron-scroll-threshold` element - '**threshold**'.

```
<iron-scroll-threshold scroll-target="document" id="threshold" on-lower-threshold="loadMoreData" lower-threshold="100">
<iron-list id="list" items="[[items]]" as="item" scroll-target="threshold" grid>
<!-- template -->
</iron-list>
</iron-scroll-threshold>
```